# Understand what it looks like standard lib functions not properly identified by IDA Pro

Tags: ida, disassembly, functions

I'm reverse engineering a piece of code that has hundreds of calls to a couple of functions I'm not exactly sure what they are doing but looks like standard library functions that do some byte reading?

They are as I currently call them `read8` and `read16` and show in IDA Pro as pseudocode:

```
int __cdecl read8(int a1)
{
  return *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 8);
}

int __cdecl read16(int a1)
{
  return *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 16);
}
```

So given a pointer `a1` do they read a single `DWORD` positioned as the 8th and 16th DWORD after the initial address of `a1`?

Answer (score 1):

> So given a pointer `a1` do they read a single `DWORD` positioned as the
>   8th and 16th DWORD after the initial address of `a1`?

No, they read a single `DWORD` positioned 8-bytes and 16-bytes (respectively) after the initial address of `a1`.

In C, this might look as follows:

```
typedef struct _S
{
    DWORD a;
    DWORD b;
    DWORD c;
    DWORD d;
    DWORD e;
} S;

S x;
DWORD c = read8(&x);
DWORD e = read16(&x);
```

Comment: I thought this was supposed to be pointer arithmetic where +8 means 8 memory allocation slots for a pointer instead of single byte positions?

Comment: What about the `*` before the first set of parenthesys, is that not dereferencing the contents in position +4 as an actual memory address and looking at that address instead to return?

Comment: In your decompilation, `a1` is an `int`, and adding to an `int` doesn't take value type sizes into account. Further questions about interpreting C code should probably be posted to http://stackoverflow.com/ instead of here.